# React Array - Merge data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js

I have the following array and I need the outcome to merge the results if the `grouptype` is the same.

```js
const locationss = [
  {
    grouptype: "Name1",
    id: "1",
    servicetype: [
      { name: "Morning", price: "5" },
      { name: "Afternoon", price: "5" },
      { name: "Full Day", price: "5" },
    ],
  },
  {
    grouptype: "Name1",
    id: "2",
    servicetype: [
      { name: "Morning1", price: "5" },
      { name: "Afternoon1", price: "5" },
      { name: "Full Day1", price: "5" },
    ],
  },
  {
    grouptype: "Name2",
    id: "3",
    servicetype: [
      { name: "Morning", price: "5" },
      { name: "Afternoon", price: "5" },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want the outcome to be, I've tried .reduce but that didn't work.

```
{
 grouptype: 'Name1',[
        { name: 'Morning', price: '5'  },
        { name: 'Afternoon', price: '5'  },   
        { name: 'Full Day', price: '5' },
        { name: 'Morning1', price: '5'  },
        { name: 'Afternoon1', price: '5'  },   
        { name: 'Full Day1', price: '5' },

]
},
{
        grouptype: 'Name2',
        id: '3',
        servicetype: [
        { name: 'Morning', price: '5'  },
        { name: 'Afternoon', price: '5'  },   
        ],
      }
```

So I can put it into a table. using firebase backed

Comment: What is supposed to happen with the `id`, you want to get rid of it?

Comment: The id is just there no reason

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group by `servicetype` then use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map the groups to the expected output structure.

```js
const locations = [
  {
    grouptype: "Name1",
    id: "1",
    servicetype: [
      { name: "Morning", price: "5" },
      { name: "Afternoon", price: "5" },
      { name: "Full Day", price: "5" },
    ],
  },
  {
    grouptype: "Name1",
    id: "2",
    servicetype: [
      { name: "Morning1", price: "5" },
      { name: "Afternoon1", price: "5" },
      { name: "Full Day1", price: "5" },
    ],
  },
  {
    grouptype: "Name2",
    id: "3",
    servicetype: [
      { name: "Morning", price: "5" },
      { name: "Afternoon", price: "5" },
    ],
  },
];

const groups = locations.reduce((all, cur) => ((all[cur.grouptype] ??= []).push(...cur.servicetype), all), {});
const output = Object.entries(groups).map(([k, v]) => ({ grouptype: k, servicetype: v }));
console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

As short explanation for this line:

```js
const groups = locations.reduce((all, cur) => ((all[cur.grouptype] ??= []).push(...cur.servicetype), all), {});
```

Here we start of with an empty object `{}`, then we check the group for each item in the array. When we don't have the group as a key in our object (always happens for the first element) then we'll create a new group, meaning we assign the key `grouptype` an empty array as a value and then push in all the servicetypes ([`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does take an [`Iterable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)). If we already have a key for the group, then we also already have an array for that group and we can just [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) in the service types again.

This logic can be implemented done quite easily using the [nullish assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment).